# Linq / Entity Framework select latest recorded for a group

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to figure out how to write a LINQ / Entity Framework query to return the latest data available for each symbol in a table.

My database table looks like this:

```
ID    symbol    price_date    price
------------------------------------
1     AAPL      2022-02-28    174.50
2     MSFT      2022-02-28    307.20
3     AAPL      2021-03-01    172.23
4     MSFT      2021-03-01    304.15
```

Not every symbol has a record for every day though.  The ID key is sequential and is safe for use as the highest ID for a given symbol will contain the latest data.

If I was writing a SQL query, the following would return what I'm looking for:

```
select prices.*
from prices 
where id in (select max(id) from prices group by symbol)
```

In Linq, I'm having trouble making this into a single query.
What I have so far is dividing it into two queries:

```
var maxIds = from pp in ctx.Prices
             group pp by pp.Symbol
                 into maxIdBySymbol
             select maxIdBySymbol.Max(pp => pp.Id);

var latestPrices = ctx.Prices.Where(it => maxIds.Contains(it.Id)).ToList();
```

Is there a way to make this a single query in LINQ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Addition: the proposed solution works, but is less efficient**
For more information see the addition at the end.

### Original Solution

So you will first make groups of records, where every group contains only records for one specific symbol. So you will have one group that contains the records for symbol AAPL, one group that contains the records for symbol MSFT, etc.

> I am trying ... query ... the latest data available for each symbol in a table.

So, once you've got the groups, you select one element in the group. According to your requirement you select the newest element, which is the element with the highest value for `PriceDate`. As you said, you could also take the element with the highest value for property `ID`. Personally I wouldn't do that, because if in a very far future your IDs are not in ascending date anymore, for instance because you add the feature to edit PriceDate after an input error.

For this, I would use the [overload of Queryable.GroupBy that has a parameter resultSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupby?view=net-6.0#system-linq-queryable-groupby-4(system-linq-iqueryable((-0))-system-linq-expressions-expression((system-func((-0-1))))-system-linq-expressions-expression((system-func((-0-2))))-system-linq-expressions-expression((system-func((-1-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-2))-3)))))). Use the resultSelector to select the one element of each group that you want.

```
var newestRecordPerSymbol = dbContext.PriceRecords

// make groups of priceRecords with same value for property Symbol
.GroupBy( priceRecord => priceRecord.Symbol,

// parameter resultSelector: for every symbol and all priceRecords
// that have this symbol, take the newest one
// = order by descending PriceDate and take the first one
(symbol, priceRecordsWithThisSymbol) => priceRecordsWithThisSymbol
    .OrderByDescending(priceRecord => priceRecord.PriceDate)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

In words: from the table of PriceRecords, make groups of PriceRecords that have the same value for property Symbol. From every combination of Symbol, and PriceRecords that have this symbol, order all PriceRecords by descending value for property PriceDate, and keep only the first one.

Every group has at least one element, so you could have used `First` as well as `FirstOrDefault`. Some versions of EntityFramework or DBMS have problems using First. If you encounter this problem, use FirstOrDefault.

If you still want to take the one with the highest ID:

```
  .OrderByDescending(priceRecord => priceRecord.ID)
  .FirstOrDefault(),
```

### Why is this solution less efficient.

In the original solution, all records in a group are sorted, and only the first one is taken. It is a bit of a waste to sort the second, third, etc. element if you will only take the first one.

In the original SQL you'll see code like:

```
select maxIdBySymbol.Max(pp => pp.Id);
```

So, not all elements are sorted. The sequence is enumerated only once, and the largest one is returned. This is way more effcient then sorting elements that you won't use anyway.

To create code like this, we need to change parameter resultSelector of the GroupBy. Let is use a method like [Max(propertySelector)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.max?view=net-6.0#system-linq-queryable-max-2(system-linq-iqueryable((-0))-system-linq-expressions-expression((system-func((-0-1)))))), or one of the overloads of [Queryable.Aggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.aggregate?view=net-6.0). Something like this:

```
// parameter resultSelector: keep the record with the largest ID
(symbol, priceRecordsWithThisSymbol) => priceRecordsWithThisSymbol
    .Max(record => record.Id);
```

Alas, although the guys from entity framework did a tremendous job, this overload of the Max method is not supported, so are none of the Aggregate methods. See [List of Supported and Unsupported Linq methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: This method worked, and I got the same data as my split query.  The query itself took about 6x as long though.  (200ms for the split query, 1200ms for the combined query).  I'm not sure what SQL is being issued behind the scenes.

Comment: If you want to see the SQL being generated by entity framework, consider to use property `DbContext.Database.Log` for example: `context.Database.Log = Console.Write`. For more information see [Entity Framework Logging Database Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception)

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `Where` with **not** `Any`:

```
ctx.Prices.Where(prices1 => !ctx.Prices.Any(prices2 => (prices2.Id > prices1.Id) && (prices1.symbol.Equals(prices2.symbol))))
```

Comment: Perhaps it is my version of .Net (4.8), but I get "Prices does not contain a definition of Any"

Comment: @JohnP you are right, it was a typo on my part. Edited my answer. I advise you to test it even though your problem was already solved, because this is quite a neat way to solve the issue.